# How do I input the items in a list using a variable as the identifier?

Tags: python, list

I have a decent background in C++ but I'm new to Python. I'm trying to write a basic program that allows the user to specify the number of shareholders in a company and then ask about each Shareholder's rating in each of three qualities (usefulness of work, significance of work, difficulty of work).

I want to store the user's ratings on these three scales somewhere and then display it later. I'm still not sure whether using 3 lists for each of the 3 qualities is the most efficient way of doing it. Anyway, what I've tried to do in the following code is assign a variable `userrem` as the identifier using which new items in the list will be added.

So, for example, the initial value of `userrem` is 0. So, my understanding is that `usefulness[userrem] = input()` should add the inputted value as the first item in the list. Then, as you can see in the code, the while loop progresses and `userrem` gets increased by 1. So I thought for the second iteration of the loop, `usefulness[userrem]=input()` should add the inputted value as the second item in the list.

However, I keep getting the error `IndexError: list assignment index out of range` right after inputting the value to `usefulness[userrem]` in the first iteration of the loop.

So, my questions are as follows:-

1. Is using lists even the most efficient way of doing this?
2. What would be an alternative way to achieve what I want to achieve?
3. Would it be better to have a list for each shareholder with three
   items each for the three qualities instead of having 3 lists with an
   unknown number of items (possibly infinite!)? But if we have a list
   for each shareholder, then the number of lists may be unknown and
   possibly infinite even though the items in each list will be only 3.
   How do I determine which approach will be the most efficient?

Thanks!

```
def func_input():  
    userrem=0 # Variable used as the identifier while adding items to the lists
    global user_n # Total number of users, accessed during input
    user_n=0 
    user_n=int(input('How many shareholders are there?'))
    while userrem<user_n:
        usefulness[userrem]=int(input('Rate the usefulness of the work performed by shareholder# '+str(userrem+1)+' [Range=0-5]'))
        significance[userrem]=int(input('Rate the significance of the work performed by shareholder# '+str(userrem+1)+' [Range=0-5]'))
        difficulty[userrem]=int(input('Rate the difficulty of the work performed by shareholder# '+str(userrem+1)+' [Range=0-5]'))
        userrem=userrem+1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do what you want is to change from a list to a dictionary:

```
usefulness = {}
significance = {}
difficulty = {}
```

It uses the same syntax as a list for accesses, and allows assignment to previously unassigned indexes.

If you'd rather stay with a list, you'll need to input into another variable then `append` to the list, or create the list at the size you need ahead of time.

Instead of having 3 lists or dictionaries, you can combine the 3 values into a tuple or list and store that in a single list/dictionary. Here's some code to demonstrate storing tuples in a list:

```
scores = [None]*user_n
for userrem in range(user_n):
    usefulness = int(input('Rate the usefulness of the work performed by shareholder# '+str(userrem+1)+' [Range=0-5]'))
    significance = int(input('Rate the significance of the work performed by shareholder# '+str(userrem+1)+' [Range=0-5]'))
    difficulty = int(input('Rate the difficulty of the work performed by shareholder# '+str(userrem+1)+' [Range=0-5]'))
    scores[userrem] = (usefulness, significance, difficulty)
```